# .NET Compact Framework: define default size to a custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, custom-controls

I'm developing a winform **Windows Mobile 5.0 or above** application with .**NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2** and **C#**.

I'm wondering if there is a way to set a default size of a custom control. When I drop it over the form (on the designer) it is always getting **200x200** as its default size.

Any advice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

1. Override the default Size property and assign this Attribute to it:

   ```
   [DefaultValue(typeof(Size), "500, 500")]
   ```
2. Set the default size you want within the constructor.

Comment: I should add that for the Compact Framework you might need to decorate this via an .xmta file. You can use this to access design time attributes that aren't compatible with CF and it also helps keep the size of the end .exe down. http://blogs.msdn.com/bluecollar/archive/2007/02/08/adding-compact-framework-design-time-attributes-or-more-fun-with-textboxes.aspx